# Angular.js decorated directive doesn't get the directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

trying to decorate typeahead directive from angular-ui-bootstrap according to [this blog post](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/) and running into some trouble. I need to replace the `keydown` binding (until some PR would fix it to behave as expected), so I figured I could fetch the directive to decorate, call link.apply(this, arguments) and then just insert the `keydown` binding again as illustrated in this code example:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap').config(function($provide)
{
    $provide.decorator('typeaheadDirective', function($delegate)
    {
        var directive = $delegate[0]; //get the current directive with that name;
        //console.log('directive', directive) // I do get the directive here, just checking

        var link = directive.link; //getting the current link function. in which we would like to replace the keybinding
        //console.log('link:', link)

        directive.compile = function()
        {
            return function(scope, element, attrs)
            {
                link.apply(this, arguments);
                //element.unbind('keydown');

                element.bind('keydown', function(evt)
                {
                    //typeahead is open and an "interesting" key was pressed

                    console.log('scope matches', scope);
                    if (scope.matches.length === 0 || HOT_KEYS.indexOf(evt.which) === -1)
                    {
                        //@alon TODO:check this
                        return;
                    }

                    evt.preventDefault();

                    if (evt.which === 40)
                    {
                        scope.activeIdx = (scope.activeIdx + 1) % scope.matches.length;
                        scope.$digest();
                    }
                    else if (evt.which === 38)
                    {
                        scope.activeIdx = (scope.activeIdx ? scope.activeIdx : scope.matches.length) - 1;
                        scope.$digest();
                    }
                    else if (evt.which === 13 || evt.which === 9)
                    {
                        if (scope.activeIdx !== -1 && scope.activeIdx !== 0)
                        {
                            scope.$apply(function()
                            {
                                scope.select(scope.activeIdx);
                            });

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            evt.stopPropagation();
                            resetMatches();
                            scope.$digest();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (evt.which === 27)
                    {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        resetMatches();
                        scope.$digest();
                    }
                });
            };
        };

        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

but I getting errors that indicate that scope.matches doesn't exist(isn't defined) - meaning that the directive original scope doesn't really run - trying this with other variables from the original directive fail with the same error. How can I fix that?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeahead creates an internal child scope. 
  Looking at the [typeahead source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/ea053b1991424c57536ccb19948ed1e74d3542ed/src/typeahead/typeahead.js):

You'll see this:

```
//create a child scope for the typeahead directive so we are not polluting original scope
//with typeahead-specific data (matches, query etc.)

var scope = originalScope.$new();

originalScope.$on('$destroy', function(){
   scope.$destroy();
});
```

As noted in the comment, `matches` and the other variables you are trying to access are on that child scope instead of the scope you're looking on.

Since that child scope isn't destroyed until the parent (`originalScope`) is destroyed you can access it via `$$childHead`.  It can be risky to use internal `$$` variables- but it's discussed in [Angular's scope documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) so hopefully that means they intend to keep this property around.

**The fix** is to add the following line after `link.apply(this, arguments);` and then use `childScope` in you decorator:

```
childScope = scope.$$childHead;
```

Add that and this line will now work:

```
console.log('scope matches', childScope.matches)
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gA9BXws4QGifgUOww0O1?p=preview)